# Append Query - Multiple Tables into Single Table

Tags: ms-access, vba, append, ms-access-2010

I have 8 queries all with the same design etc to make a new table but for different criteria's and would like to append them into one single table.

Is there any way with VBA code or possibly UNION to do this?

```
SELECT tbl_SCCMQ.CONTRACT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER, tbl_SCCMQ.BP_Partner, tbl_SCCMQ.CONTRACT_NUMBER, tbl_SCCMQ.BILL_TO_DATE, tbl_SCCMQ.CONTRACT_START_DATE, tbl_SCCMQ.AGEING_DATE, tbl_SCCMQ.DateDiff, tbl_SCCMQ.PAYMENT_TYPE, tbl_SCCMQ.BP_Type, tbl_SCCMQ.[Next Bill Due Date], tbl_SCCMQ.[BAND], tbl_SCCMQ.RAG, tbl_SCCMQ.BILL_STATUS INTO tbl_01_Resi_CCQ_R1_4_Never_Billed_NoSS
FROM tbl_SCCMQ
WHERE (((tbl_SCCMQ.BP_Type)="B2C") AND ((tbl_SCCMQ.RAG) Like "R*") AND ((tbl_SCCMQ.BILL_STATUS)="First") AND ((tbl_SCCMQ.BILL_BLOCK) Is Null) AND ((tbl_SCCMQ.BILL_LOCK) Is Null) AND ((tbl_SCCMQ.INVOICE_LOCK) Is Null));
```

Here are two tables,

```
qry_01_Resi_CCQ_R1_4_Never_Billed_NoSS

qry_02_SME_CCQ_R1_4_Never_Billed_NoSS
```

and would like them all importing into main table "Data"

I am quite new to Access and VBA etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question looks like you know how to solve the problem.

Note: queries 1 to 8 must have the same number of fields and datatypes must be consistent for each field's ordinal position (asserted in your question.)

SQL syntax to create a new table (Data) from the queries:

```
select *
INTO Data
from (
select * from query1
union all
select * from query2
union all
...
union all
select * from query8
) as queryData
```

or
SQL syntax to append data to existing table:

```
INSERT INTO Data
select *
from (
select * from query1
union all
select * from query2
union all
...
union all
select * from query8
) as queryData
```

VBA syntax to run the query in code:

```
dim db as dao.database: set db = Currentdb
dim strSQL as string

strSQL = "...." ' as above
db.execute strSQL
```